The product rule and the third kinematic equation
I'm trying to find physics-based examples for the rules of calculus. Using the product rule on the third kinematic equation to find the velocity is one such example. I'm deriving the correct equation for velocity but I'm not completely sure I'm using the product rule correctly.
$\frac{d}{dt} (v_i t + \frac{1}{2} at^2) = \frac{d}{dt} v_i t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} at^2$
The first term would be $\frac{d}{dt} v_i \cdot t + v_i \cdot \frac{d}{dt}t$ Giving $0 \cdot t + v_i \cdot 1 = v_i$.
And the second term would be $\frac{d}{dt} a \cdot t^2 + a \cdot \frac{d}{dt}t^2$ Giving $0 \cdot t^2 + a \cdot 2t = 2at$ And given we have $\frac{1}{2}$ out front it's $at$.
So in total we have the fairly obvious $v = v_i + at$. And I /think/ I have applied the product rule correctly.
My question is that I'm saying $\frac{d}{dt} v_i = 0$ but surely since velocity does change with time (v = $\frac{d}{t}$) then can that be right? The same question applies to $\frac{d}{dt} a = 0$ since acceleration can be seen as (a = $\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$). Thanks

What do you understand $v_i$ and $a$ and $v_i t + at^2/2$ to represent?

Note that $v_i$ represents the initial velocity, not the time-varying velocity $v(t)$   In fact, note that $v(t)=v_i+at$, and therefore $v(0)=v_i$.
As far as acceleration, the symbol $a$ is assumed to be a constant.  Typically, one begins with acceleration equal to constant, $a$.  Then, integrating over time from $0$ to $t$, we find that
$$\begin{align}
at&=\int_0^t a\,dt'\\\\
&=\int_0^t x''(t')\,dt'\\\\
&=x'(t)-x'(0)\\\\
&=v(t)-v_i\tag1
\end{align}$$
Solving $(1)$ for $v(t)$, we see that $v(t)=v_i+at$.  Integrating again yields the kinematic equation
$$x(t)=x_i+v_it+\frac12 at^2$$
where $x(t)$ locates the position of the object experiences constant acceleration, $a$, has initial velocity $v_i$, and is located at $x_i$ at time $0$.
So, you have applied the product rule correctly.

Thanks for your first sentence. After I wrote that all out I started to wonder my problem was that I was thinking about the /average/ velocity and acceleration that do vary with time, rather than the instantaneous, so thanks for confirming and clarifying.

In as afar as your explanation for acceleration I'm a bit lost due to my unfamiliarity with calculus. But I'd attempt integration by parts to get the velocity: $\int{a * 1} = a * \int{1} + \int({\frac{d}{dt} a * 1}) = a * t + \int{0 * 1} = at$ Would that be correct?

Yes.  But it's simpler.  The integral of a constant is the product of that constant and the length of the integration interval
